# Installing curl.h library

Tags: libraries, c, curl

Could you help me install curl.h library?

Comment: There should be a curl-dev (or something like that) package available.

Comment: How did you installed the curl package?

Comment: `sudo aptitude install libcurl-dev` is the command to install libcurl on Ubuntu. Unless you have particular reasons, I suggest using the package provided by your distribution, not to install by hand.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Debian does not have `libcurl-dev`. It has `libcurl4-openssl-dev` and `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` and I don't think Ubuntu would differ.

Comment: `libcurl-dev` is a virtual package on Debian. I have it on Debian/Sid.

Answer (score 129):

```
apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

or

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

or

```
apt-get install libcurl4-nss-dev
```

depending on whether you want to use [gnutls](https://www.gnutls.org/), [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) or [nss](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/) for SSL.

Comment: Only improvement to this answer would be to explain why you would choose one over the other.

Comment: @DobesVandermeer, please could you explain that? I don't know the actual benefits of using one lib or the other.

Comment: The reason for this divide is a [licensing issue](https://curl.haxx.se/legal/distro-dilemma.html). **The OpenSSL variant is the most tried and tested,** but is not GPL compatible.

Comment: Is this answer still current?

Comment: @ZachSmith, yes, it is. And is expected to remain so for many more years, except perhaps the number 4 in the package name might be replaced with higher one.

Comment: Why does aptitude offer 2 versions of curl.h? I don't want this burden of choice, I just want to compile a program that depends on curl.

Comment: @TomasZubiri, three, now. If it only depends on a tls implementation indirectly and you are not going to distribute it, pick any. Otherwise you have to pick the legally or technically compatible one.

Comment: As the licensing link above is broken let me share [license issue](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/gpl-v3-with-openssl-exception) explanation which includes a way how to include OpenSSL variant into any GPL project.